# Segue between two view controllers

Tags: ios, ios6, uistoryboard

[image]

On my storyboard (shown above), I have a ViewController which holds an MKMapView with annotations. These annotations hold a disclosure icon, which when tapped, should navigate the user to another ViewController. To do so I've created a push segue between the view controllers. I've then given it an identifier of 'showDetail' and implemented the following code.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
}
```

However I get the following error.

```
Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'showDetail'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

Where am I going wrong? I have tried changing my source UIViewController to a UINavigationController, but the view then just displays as a black screen.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your storyboard with both ViewControllers?

Comment: @Mariusz question updated! Thank you.

Comment: Try to embed your target ViewController in a NavigationController and drag your segue from the MapViewController to the NavigationController.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You actually have to set your UIViewController as the root controller of a UINavigationController (or pushed through from a view controller w/ a navcontroller). To do that

- Drag a new navigation controller into your storyboard - it will by
  default be attached to a tableview controller
- Delete the tableview controller Right click on the navgiation
  controller, and connect the "Root View Controller" property to your
  existing view controller
- Move the entry point arrow from your    view controller to the root
  view controller

Comment: It works! Thank you. Just to check I've got it right, I now have a TabBarController and a UINavigationController. Is there not a controller which can handle both?

Comment: Checkout this documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH6-SW1   The steps are under the heading 
"Creating the Objects Using a Storyboard".

Answer (score 40):

Simplest way to do this is to select the View controller you want to be the root of your navigation hierarchy and choose

```
Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller
```

This creates the new navigation controller and hooks up everything up for you.

Answer (score 0):

check this steps:
 1. to click connection between two view controller.
 2. click attribute inspector
 3. set identifier to "showDetail".
 4. save and run.