# iOS 7 NavigationController Segue Crash

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, ios8

I have a NavigationController as Initial View and a ViewController as the root view. From that root view i am trying to do a segue with:

```
[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue" sender:self];
```

There´s another view controller in my storyboard and i gave the segue the correct identifier. On iOS 8 it works perfect, but on iOS 7 it crashes with the following message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'Segue'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

I don´t get why it´s not working on iOS 7...

UPDATE: Here´s my Storyboard:

[image]

Comment: you can check the storyboard segue. Can i see the your storyboard image

Comment: I checked it already...What exactly should I check?

Comment: your app entry point is a navigation controller?

Comment: It seems like Segue doesn't exist

Comment: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue" sender:self]; try this. Remove navigationController.

Comment: Yes, entry point is the nav controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that your **segue** has the `UINavigationController` as its source.

A `UINavigationController` should not perform a **segue**. It should only be connected to a `rootViewController`, which may be a `UIViewController` (or its subclass). A **segue** should be performed from the  `rootViewController` of the `UINavigationController`. The **segue** should have the `rootViewController` as its source and some other `UIViewController` (or its subclass) as its destination.

Your screenshot shows that your `UINavigationController` is connected to a `rootViewController`. You now need to set the `rootViewController` as the source of the **segue** (having identifier `Segue`), which currently has your `UINavigationController` as its source. Now, from the `rootViewController`, call

```
[self performSegueWithIndentifier:@"Segue" sender:nil]
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. But I couldn't understand your solution. Kindly explain your answer a little more and also tell why it's working on iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue" sender:self];
```

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<RootGuideController: 0x7a67f590>) has no segue with identifier 'Segue''

Answer (score 0):

use `Self` if you are already performing `segue` from within the `rootViewController`.
If not then try this .

```
[self.navigationController.viewControllers[0] performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue" sender:nil];
```

Hope this will help you.

I think you have no `segue` in `storyboard` from `rootViewController` to other `viewController` with name @"`Segue`".

Comment: Same crash: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<RootGuideController: 0x7897b470>) has no segue with identifier 'Segue''

Comment: @chrizstone I think you have no segue in storyboard from rootViewController to other viewController with name @"Segue".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049668/segue-between-two-view-controllers check this answer

Comment: Thats, correct i only have a segue from the nav controller to other controller named "Segue". It´s working on iOS 8 like this

Comment: Normally you have a segue from a concrete view controller and the navigation controller is just the container. Everything else will lead to quirky behavior as in your case.